# How do you find nodes with no outgoing edges in networkx?

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

I am trying to find nodes with no outgoing edges in a digraph in networkx.

Is there a way to do this? I found [isolates](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.isolate.isolates.html#networkx.algorithms.isolate.isolates) but that finds edges without incoming or outgoing edges, and I don't want that.

Comment: Not sure if there's anything built in, but what about just using `out_degree` and then filtering the results?

Answer (score 5):

If `G` is your `DiGraph`, you can get an iterator of sinks through

```
(node for node, out_degree in G.out_degree_iter() if out_degree == 0)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'out_degree_iter'`

Comment: @alper; as of NetworkX 2, `out_degree_iter` no longer exists; you can simply use `out_degree` instead.

Answer (score 5):

> "methods that returned an iterator [have been removed](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html)"

in NetworkX 2.x, so @fuglede's answer needs a minor update:

```
(node for node, out_degree in G.out_degree() if out_degree == 0)
```

The view/reporting API provided by [.out_degree](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_degree.html#networkx.DiGraph.out_degree) in 2.x provides an OutDegreeView over `(node, out_degree)` pairs, making this approach slightly simpler than @Fony Lew's.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with `out_degree_iter()` as it returns an error. So I searched for other solutions on NetworkX documentation and found this is working. (`G` is a `DiGraph`)

```
[node for node in G.nodes if G.out_degree(node) == 0]
```

Note, in case of finding incoming degree or edges. You can just simply change from `out_degree` to `in_degree`

Ref: [networkx.DiGraph.out_degree](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_degree.html)